# Sorry we can't play this file on your phone. Error code 80072f30

Tags: xbox-music

I'm using Windows Phone 8 and downloaded songs via Xbox Music app. If I disable data connection while listing to the music, it'll give me this error message.

```
Sorry we can't play this file on your phone. 
Error code 80072f30
```

Why does it require data connection to play the music after I've downloaded the music to my phone already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *download* a song through XBox Music (without actually *buying* it), the app requires a data connection to validate your license to play the song.  This is commonly referred to as Digital Rights Management, or DRM for short.

If you *buy* the song or album, you can move the file to any other device to play it, and can play it on the phone without having a data connection active.

Comment: Sign out of the account or app and sign back in to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Xbox Music is a streaming service, just like Spotify, Grooveshark or Deezer. Consequently if you disable the data connection, the stream will be interrupted and you will not be able to listen to the end of the song.

Comment: That'll apply if I'm streaming music, but why would data connection is still required after the music is downloaded to the device?

Comment: -1 because XBox Music supports playing locally stored music, as well as streaming.